# How to convert a number to a string in XtraReport

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

In Crystal Reports the `ToWords` command converts a number into a string.

My question is: How can I achieve this in a DevExpress XtraReport?

Comment: This is not supported as of now as explained [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q312959.aspx). However, it guides the dev on how to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey… As there is no any direct functionality to do this. It is possible by changing the XRLabel.Text property within its XRLabel.BeforePrint event handler in XtraReports. For example, you have to follow the link: http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=46. Hope this helps you!